# LWJGL - Can the Assimp bindings be used without the core JAR

Tags: java, awt, lwjgl, assimp

I wanted to update to LWJGL 3 from 2, but searches online shows it doesn't really work (properly? at all?) with Java GUI toolkits.
The code that I am working on has the GL context in an AWT canvas among many other GUI components, and it's not really realistic now to change to a GL-based GUI library.

But at the end of the day, updating GL is not quite important to me, rather what I really want is the Assimp bindings, assuming they are more or less complete.

I thought of just using the Assimp module itself with the existing code, however it seems to require the core LWJGL 3 JAR, which then causes runtime clashes with the LWJGL 2 one.

Is there a way to actually use LWJGL 3 with other GUI in modern times?
Otherwise, can I somehow use the Assimp bindings without using LWJGL itself, without runtime issues?

Comment: Thanks that looks promising, I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Assimp-port for Java, which you can find here [JAssimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/tree/master/port/jassimp). You can build them from the current master or there shall be precompiled packages ready to use.